# Is there a more efficient way to set a session variable for each view?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask. I have quite a few views that take parameters, say `<name>`. I'd like to store `<name>` in a session variable without having to do that for every view. Is that possible?

```
@app.route('/home/',defaults={'name':None})
@app.route('/home/<name>/')
def name():
  session['name'] = name
  return ...

@app.route('/another/',defaults={'name':None})
@app.route('/another/<name>/')
def name():
  session['name'] = name # repetitive
  return ...
```

Comment: This seems to do what you want, but I'm not familiar enough with Flask to provide a 'real' answer: [URL Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/urlprocessors/)

Comment: I'm new to flask as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you get `name` as view parameter. So in this case you can write own decorator:

```
def set_session(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(name, *args, **kwargs):
        session['name'] = name
        return fn(name, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@app.route('/home/',defaults={'name':None})
@app.route('/home/<name>/')
@set_session
def name(name):
    return ...
```

You also can update `Flask` view:

```
class MyApp(Flask):
    def add_url_rule(self, rule, endpoint=None, view_func=None, **options):
        if (view_func is not None):
            view_func = set_session(view_func)
        return super(MyApp, self).add_url_rule(rule, endpoint,
                                               view_func, **options)
```

Probably best solution is use pluggable views: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/. It more useful if you have several decorators.